# Android File Permissions issues on FilesDir()

Tags: java, android, android-internal-storage

I need to use a file in my application. If i upload the file to Data/Data/APP/files then it is added with -rw-rw-rw permissions which i can then use in my application. If i programatically write the file to getFilesDir() the exact same directory, i can see the 2 exact files in the same directory, however the programatically saved file has permissions -rw------- i cannot then access the file in my app using getfilesDir().
this is how the file is saved:

```
    public void writeFileOnInternalStorage(Context mcoContext,String sFileName, String sBody){
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }

        try{
            File gpxfile = new File(file, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

How can i get the correct permissions to use the file. It may well not be a permissions issue it maybe the way i am saving the file? It is a .graphml extension file.

Comment: You do not need any permission for getFilesDir().

Comment: If i upload the file to  Data/Data/APP/files . Such a path does not exist to begin with. And what do you mean with upload? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: `File file = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "");` That does not define a File object with a name. It defines a directory. Further that code does not save anything. It only creates a File object.

Comment: In terms of the file path apologies i was just being shorthanded i thought you would understand where getFilesDir() stores files to. I have added the complete method to save the file.

Comment: `File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "");` That is a confusing statement. Better: `File file = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();`.

Comment: `i thought you would understand where getFilesDir() stores files to.` Yes i know. And not to Data/Data/APP/files. Further you did not tell us how you are doing an upload.

Comment: And as you have problems reading a file you should also post the used code for that.

Comment: `It is a .graphml extension file.`. Then why cant we see that in your code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by cannot access your file?

Take a look at this documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), you don't need permission to access (read and write) files inside App-Specific Directory.

---

**Edit:**

I'm assuming that you already stored the file to the disk.

Please note that to read and write files inside App-Specific Directory doesn't require permission. You can read it using this simple code.

```
public File readFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    // do other stuff, like checking if the file exist, etc.
    return file;
}
```

It doesn't matter what file extension it is, as long as the file exists, you will get it.

Actually there are so many articles that already cover this topic, please take a look to understand this topic better.

Comment: i have two files they are exactly the same sat in the app-specific directory, they have the same name the same content. the only difference being is as above the way they werre added to the directory, and the permissions as above. When i run the app, obviously with only one of the files in there if i use the one with rwrwrw(uploaded) then it works fine, if i use the one saved rw---- then the app cannot see it and throws an error as if it is not tthere?

Comment: How can you programmatically choose the one or the other?

Comment: I do not choose i delete one or the other, that is the test i perform. when uploaded it gets rwrwrw it works, when saved it gets rw---- it doesnt. Same file same dir, but not there at the same time. I need to be able to save rather than uploading it, and be able to use it.

Comment: You choose? That does not match `i can see the 2 exact files in the same directory, `.

Comment: @HTBuild I've updated my answer, I'm pretty sure you'll find many blogs that cover this topic, you should take a look at it to understand better.